# Limpar apenas o campo que pretendo

Tags: jquery

tenho este script:

```
$(".btn_contact").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./Inserir16",
        data: $("#feedback_form16").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
        }, 
        error: function(data){
            $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
        },
        complete: function()
        { 
            $("#feedback_form16").find('input').val(''); //clear text
        }           
    });

});
```

Desta forma elimina todos os campos input, mas pretendo só eliminar um campo especifico do formulário, que tem o nome e id de Qtd.
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou `$("#Qtd").val('')`?

Comment: @dvd, já tentei mas não resultou

Comment: Ok! Mas vc colocou em qual das funções?

Comment: Na função complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente seu HTML possui `id`s duplicados e usando `#Qtd` não está encontrando o elemento correto. Uma página HTML não pode ter o mesmo `id` em mais de um elemento.

Coloque no `input` que você quer limpar um atributo `data-*`, por exemplo:

```
<input data-qtd="Qtd"...>
```

E no `complete` do Ajax coloque:

```
$("input[data-qtd='Qtd']").val('')
```

Answer (score 2):

É bem simples, se você está usando jQuery, é só usar esse código:

```
$("input[name='nome-do-input']").val('');
```

Ou, se houver inputs com o nome que você quer em outros lugares que não o formulário que você deseja limpar, pode seguir a linha de raciocínio do seu código atual assim:

```
$("#feedback_form16").find('input[name="nome-do-input"]').val(''); //clear text
```

Comment: desta forma insere na mesma na tabela, mas não limpa o input

Comment: Essa função limpa sim o input, com toda a certeza. Agora o problema pode ser que na sua função, você não tem a input gerada na sua página no momento que você tenta limpá-la, OU você está populando os dados do input após limpá-lo. Para tirar essa dúvida, jogue esse código: `$("input[name='nome-do-input']").val('');` no Console do Developer Tools do seu navegador e veja que o input será limpo.

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Atualmente vc limpa todos os campos do formulario no complete function() com esse código:

```
$("#feedback_form16").find('input').val(''); //clear text
```

Então vc precisa limpar somente o input quantidade, certo?
Adicione um id no input desejado, assim:

```
<input type="text" name="quantidade" id="quantidade" />
```

E no complete function() referencie ele dessa forma:

```
$("#quantidade").val(''); //clear text
```

Comment: apliquei o racicionio que indicou mas não eliminou o valor no input quantidade

Comment: experimenta colocar esse trecho $("#quantidade").val(''); //clear text       fora do complete function, dentro da estrutura do click function, porem fora do agrupamento ajax, pq parece que não está ocorrendo o successo da função disposta na url definida em seu ajax "inserir16"

Comment: Mas se colocar para limpar todos, ocorre o sucesso e limpa os inputs todos

Comment: Coloca o html do input aqui, para vermos como está

Comment: tenta colocar o $("#quantidade").val(''); dentro do success function()